# Horizontal scroll bar prevents text box wrapping

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, word-wrap

I am trying to make `TextBox` to wrap text and grow with the `Window`. That works if I don't set `ScrollViewer`'s `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property. But if I do, `TextBox` will grow infinitely. The problem is solved by setting `MaxWidth` property to the TextBox, but in that case `TextBox` does not grow beyond the `MaxWidth` value. My idea was then to bind `MaxWidth` to `ColumnDefinition`'s `ActualWidth`, but that also doesn't work because `ColumnDefinition`'s `ActualWidth` property is not a `DependencyProperty`. Here is my code:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name:" Margin="5" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="200" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="5"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want a horizontal scroll bar if the text is supposed to wrap anyway?

Comment: @FredrikMörk I want scroll bar because of MinWidth. If user makes window smaller than the MinWidth value i wan't the scroll bar to be shown. And also, there might be other controls on the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Name:" Margin="5" />
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox MinWidth="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="5" MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't want the ScrollViewer to be around each TextBox. I have around 10 on the page.

Comment: @Vale do you have more than on TextBlock/TextBox(other control?) pairs in the same ScrollViewer? You can still use the same binding to MaxWidth, allthough you might want to use a converter to adjust the value some..